# PostGIS create topogeom from existing geometry column

Tags: postgis, postgis-topology

I tried to create topogeom using postgis.topology extention.

```
SELECT topology.AddTopoGeometryColumn('roadtopo','public','roads','topogeom ','LINESTRING');

UPDATE roads SET topogeom = topology.toTopoGeom(geom,'roadtopo',1,0.00028);
```

But I receive an error;

> ERROR:  column "topogeom" of relation "roads" does not exist
> LINE 1: UPDATE roads SET topogeom = topology.toTopoGeom(geom,'roadto...

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check your execution logs, does it compain about a) not having a `roadtopo` topo layer, and/or b) `feature_type` being `LINESTRING` (has to be `LINE`)?

Comment: In execution logs it doesn't compain about roadtopo and LINESTRING, I also tried as LINE and the result is same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first request you write `'topogeom '` and no `'topogeom'`, so the name of your column is : "topogeom " (with a space).

This request should work :

```sql
UPDATE roads SET "topogeom " = topology.toTopoGeom(geom,'roadtopo',1,0.00028);
```

Of course you can also correct the name of the topology column :

```sql
SELECT topology.AddTopoGeometryColumn('roadtopo','public','roads','topogeom','LINESTRING');
```

```sql
UPDATE roads SET topogeom = topology.toTopoGeom(geom,'roadtopo',1,0.00028);
```